# Shortest code to check if a number is in a range in JavaScript

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

This is how I checkout to see if a number is in a range (in between two other numbers):

```
var a = 10,
    b = 30,
    x = 15,
    y = 35;

x < Math.max(a,b) && x > Math.min(a,b) // -> true
y < Math.max(a,b) && y > Math.min(a,b) // -> false
```

I have to do this math in my code a lot and I'm looking for shorter equivalent code.

This is a shorter version I came up with. But I am sure it can get much shorter:

```
a < x && x < b
true
a < y && y < b
false
```

But downside is I have to repeat `x` or `y`

Comment: `a<x&x<b` will return `1` or `0`, and is 7 characters shorter.

Comment: For code-golf purposes [beary605](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4303/beary605)'s solution is best, but if you're using the code a lot you'd be better off declaring a function like `within(a,b)` or `inrange(a,b)` somewhere in your code and using that. It's instantly obvious what it does and therefore easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: beary605, your solution won't work because it will always return 0 when b<a even if x is in between a and b (for example when `a=20; b=10; x=15`)

Comment: @Yellos  `a` is supposed to be the *minimum* while `b` is *max*. Your example shows the minimum higher than the maximum!

Answer (score 13):

13 chars, checks both variants a<b and b<a

```
(x-a)*(x-b)<0
```

In C may be used expression (may be also in JavaScript). 11 chars, No multiplications (fast)

```
(x-a^x-b)<0
```

Answer (score 9):

```
a<x==x<b
```

JavaScript, 8 chars.

Comment: `0<0==0<1` ->
`false`

Comment: I like Yellos answer. And `0>=0==0<1` returns `true`

Comment: @Mohsen the OP's request was a number **in between** two limiting numbers, not including them. Therefore, `0<0==0<1` **should** return false, because in that case, 0 is the lower limit, but also the number that should be in between the range. And they are equal.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript,  7 bytes

```
a<n&n<b
```

Comment: Golfed: ```a<n<b```

Comment: @A̲̲ That doesn't work in Javascript